# Google Sheets SKU automated data

Tags: function, google-sheets, input, output, sku

I'm looking to create a CSV that automates product colour and size variables *(Columns I and K, highlighted yellow and blue)* based on the value I put in the SKU *(Column N, highlighted green)*.

I would like to create a SKU *(Column N)* that looks similar to `1-5` which would have the output of `Blue` *(Column I)* and `5` *(Column K)*.

Another example of this could be `2-11` which would have an output of `Red` (Column I) and `11` (Column K).

The aim of this is to automate the process by assigning each colour and shoe size with it's own value to save the client as much time as possible.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Diagram]

**Link to CSV**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lc8XcHDMyMFGAkegTRrBLLTlQN8oNVbU430vT0aeP4Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Tom, do mean that you just want a formula in N (to replace what is currently there) that just concatenates the values from columns I and K to form a SKU?  Won't ={"Variant SKU";ARRAYFORMULA(I2:I & " - " & K2:K)}  put in N1 do the trick?  Be sure to delete everything in cells N2 and below to allow it to fill the column, or you get the #REF error.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Kirkg13, thank you for your help. I'm after something similar; I'm aiming to have a formula that assigns each colour and shoe size a value E.g. 1 - blue, 2 - red 3 - green and 50 - size 5, 60 size 6, 100 - size 10, 115 - size 11.5 etc. So when these are types into the N column in the 1-50 format, it automatically fills out columns 'I' and 'K' with those values. The idea is so the I will only have to fill out the SKU column rather than all three when adding several hundred products. Since there's a finite number of colours and sizes, but unlimited products, it seemed the logical option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Copy of product-list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lc8XcHDMyMFGAkegTRrBLLTlQN8oNVbU430vT0aeP4Y/edit#gid=2062994227)

I1: `=arrayformula(if(A1:A="Handle","Option1 Value",IF(LEFT(N1:N)="1","Blue",IF(LEFT(N1:N)="2","Red","Green"))))`

K1: `=arrayformula(if(A1:A="Handle","Option2 Value",IF(LEN(MID(N1:N,3,3))>2,LEFT(MID(N1:N,3,3),2)&"."&RIGHT(MID(N1:N,3,3)),LEFT(MID(N1:N,3,3),2))))`

Comment: How would you rewrite the formula in K1 to display/format the numbers in that column to be the same as the content I've written in column L? So '000' in column  N would be displayed as '0' in column K, '150' as '1.5', '200' as '2' etc. I've duplicated your spreadsheet with the revised data. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Is is also possible to have colour variables as characters or numbers mixed with characters? For example if I wanted a variable of 'Yellow' input as '1Y' or 'Cream' 'C'. I've included examples of these in the spreadsheet too to try and illustrate what I'm saying.

Comment: Glad the solution works for you!


"So '000' in column N would be displayed as '0' in column K, '150' as '1.5', '200' as '2' etc." 
You cannot directly rewrite the formula in K1 due to the presence of ARRAYFORMULA ().

Try this: 
K2: `=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(split(N2,"-")),{0;1})/100`

K3: `=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(split(N3,"-")),{0;1})/100`

etc.

Those you will have to copy this formula to the entire range of column K.

If you want to avoid this copying and use ARRAYFORMULA in cell K1, try asking a new question with these requirements.

Comment: That's worked great, thank you. Is is also possible to have colour variables as characters or numbers mixed with characters? For example if I wanted a variable of 'Yellow' input as '1Y' or 'Cream' 'C'?

Comment: @Tom, I found a solution in order not to copy the formula from K2 to K3, K4, etc. 
Use this formula:
K1: 
`=arrayformula(IF(A1:A="Handle","Option2 Value",INDEX(SPLIT(N1:N, "-"),,2)/100))`

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you. Sorry, I should have phrased my question better - Is it possible to have a colour value of E.g. '1M' (Multicoloured) if there is already a colour value of '1' (Blue)? I've tried to add it to the spreadsheet. Having a colour value as just a character works great though.

Comment: Yes, try this formula in I1: 
`=arrayformula(IF(A1:A="Handle","Option1 Value",IF(LEN(INDEX(SPLIT(N1:N, "-"),,1))>1,"Multicoloured",IF(LEFT(N1:N)="1","Blue",IF(LEFT(N1:N)="2","Red",IF(LEFT(N1:N)="C","Cream",))))))`

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for all your help, you've been monumentally helpful. May I ask one last question? How would I combine the data in column 'B' in the same way you have for 'I' and 'K'? E.g. 'Lightweight Trainers' with a value of 'L32' added to the front of what's in column 'N' so we would be left with a SKU of e.g. 'L32-1-000'. I've added an example in the spreadsheet to illustrate what I'm saying. Sorry, this is a complete oversight on my part. That should be the last thing that needs changing. Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understood this correctly: "How would I combine the data in column 'B' in the same way you have for 'I' and 'K'?". Do you want to see "L32-1-000" in column B?

Comment: I would like to combine the data from column B with the data that's currently in column N. So column N would display "L32-1-000" etc. Essentially repeating what you've done with column 'I' and 'K' with column 'B' and merging the three together.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Cells in columns I and K receive data from column N. This is the original column from which the dancing begins :-) If it contains a formula that depends on columns I and K, which depend on column N, then we will get a circular reference. Sorry again, maybe I don't understand because of my poor knowledge of English.

Comment: No worries, I should explain better! Exactly, I would like the cells in column B to receive data from column N as well, exactly the same as you have done with column I and column K. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Oh, if so, then it is very easy! Use the formula in B1: `=arrayformula(IF(A1:A="Handle","Title","L32-"&N1:N))`

Comment: We're very close! I'm looking at having the "L32-1-000" display in column N and the Product title in column B.

Comment: That would mean column B behaves exactly the same as column I and column K, displaying information that is set in column N.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227632/discussion-between-boris-baublys-and-tom).